# Xylitol with beer?

Tags: lemonade

I'm interested in brewing what I've heard is called a "raddler". It's pretty much a lemonade beer I am aware of some technical issues with this  style  such as lemonade is sweet and yeast eats sugar but let's say all goes well and the yeast eats the sugar leaving me with a tart lemon flavor beer.

I was wondering if anyone tried adding xylitol to the beer before bottling or kegging(in my case). Does the xylitol affect the yeast in any way? Will the lemon juice's high acidity affect the xylitol?

Thanks so much.

Kobi

Answer (score 2):

Just mix it at serving time. That's how many soda/juice/etc + beer drinks are made. You are right, if you try to do it up front with a non-alcoholic beverage, it's going to affect the fermentation.

Comment: Thanks for that info I've read about that I'm not worried about the fermentation I really just want to know if xylitol being that it isn't a sugar will 1. Affect the yeast 2. Have any sort of reaction with lemon juice because of the lemon juice's high acidity

Comment: I don't know whether or not it is fermentable. If not, it won't affect the yeast. You could treat it as an adjunct like milk sugar. I really would avoid much xylitol though, as it has negative affects on people's bowels, especially in the kind of quantity you might end up with here :)

Comment: Haha thanks I'll try it, it shouldn't be much though to sweeten five gallons do u know an other sweetener I could use instead that wouldn't be fermented by the yeast milk sugar is out as the person to whom this is going is lactose intolerant

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [stevia](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=12888)?

It's much sweeter than sugar so it will only take a little bit to reach the sweetness level you're after, plus it's unfermentable.  Is there a recipe you're thinking of using, or you're still in the 'just thinking' phase?

Comment: I've brewed this style once, by taking the hydrometer sample and just adding lemon juice and sugar in a half cup recipe and then just multiply to reach five gallons and what I was left with was a very refreshing tart (not sweet) lemon beer so I just figured if I add a unfermentable sweetner right before bottling should do the trick I just don't know which one or how much and if I keg the  batch does that change the amounts

Comment: I think use stevia - as for how much, your method seems good (start with a small sample and scale up) - it shouldn't change if you bottle or keg

Answer (score 1):

Xylitol is not fermentable.  So I would expect you could add it after fermentation has finished, to increase the sweetness without increasing the alcohol levels or acidity.  Or, as has been suggested, add it when you open the bottles, but that might take a while to dissolve properly.  I don't see how it could react with the lemon in a bad way, as it's just a sugar alcohol and is used all the time in diabetic treats and in candies and gums which often have citrus flavors.